# Sql Server Error 18452 The Login Is From An Untrusted Domain

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

I have two MS SQL databases under the same server: I connect normally to one of them using MS SQL Server Management Studio with Windows Authentication but when I try to connect to the other I get the error stated in the title of this question.

I am a total ignorant when it comes to Windows and I do not even know what other details are required for someone to be able to help me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please confirm if I understood you well: You have 1 server with 2 instances. You can connect to one of them using Windows Authentication, and you cannot connect to your second instance. You connect remotely from pc in the same domain, right?

Comment: @sepupic I am connecting locally, using SQL Server Management Studio. The rest you understood well. Cheers

Comment: Do you use . for default instance and .\InstName for named instance or do you use IP?

Comment: @sepupic I hope I understand you: in both cases I use the server name and DB name in the connection dialog, like this: "MACHINE-NAME\DB-NAME".

Comment: I hope that you use **instance** name and not db-name, but are your instances both named? Did you try to use localhost instead of MACHINE-NAME?

Comment: @sepupic I have just tried with `localhost` and **it worked**. Curiously, once connected, the label shows this "localhost\DB-NAME (SQL Server 12.0.5207.0 - MACHINE-NAME\Administrator)". Maybe I can set `localhost` as server name, for the application will connect locally, but would be nice to find out the real problem. Cheers

Comment: @sepupic As for your other concern, I think you are right: it is the instance name, and not the DB name. How can I know if both instances are named?

Comment: >>>How can I know if both instances are named<<< If you used pc\InstanceName instead of just pc, your instances are NAMED. If you had default instance you could connect to it locally using just localhost

Comment: To resolve your problem you should edit your HOSTS file as described here. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/09/06/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-connect-to-login-failed-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain-and-cannot-be-used-with-windows-authentication-microsoft-sql-server-error-18452/

Comment: @sepupic I had already tried that (hosts file) before posting this question, but it makes no difference. In fact, as I said, the other instance works just fine, and both instances are in the same machine.

Comment: What row did you add to host?

Comment: @sepupic I added "127.0.0.1 localhost". This I understand because I come from the Unix world, where we have the hosts file aswell. But, again, it makes no difference; I edited the file and restarted the instance with same result.

Comment: No, you have a problem with MACHINE-NAME, so you should add this as a name

Comment: @sepupic Ok, I see your point. I tried that, but it still won't work. In fact, remember that I connect successfully to the other instance **using the same machine name**. The problem must be other.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Windows+R
2. Type services.msc
3. Click OK
4. Go to SQL services
5. Right click on it and go to Properties
6. Click on Log On
7. Click Browse
8. Write Local on Text field ‘Enter the object name to select’
9. Click OK
10. Reset this passwords
11. Simply click Apply
12. Click Ok and Ok once again
13. Restart the service and try to login again

Comment: Hi @Priyanka, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I am not able to test your solution because it's been a long time since I don't work on that Windows server. I will accept your answer if anybody else around here can confirm that it works. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Well I was seeing that when you tried localhost it worked, I'd say next time take a look to SPN's because this seems a SPN problem ;-)

Cheers mate